# How to bake roughness (and metallic) maps

Tags: texturing

I know that there are a few questions on this, but they are a bit old, and some of them I don't quite get. How do I bake roughness (and metallic) maps from an image texture?

I've tried recreating the roughness map of an image texture that I got off of texture.com using the bake roughness in blender, and got completely different results.

I've also watched [this tutorial on roughness map baking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BR7maafKzjs), but in the tutorial, he seems to be already have a roughness map ready, and is showing how to combine multiple maps into one map, not how to bake a texture map.

So how do I properly create roughness maps? I use gimp to create my own textures, so if there's a way to create them in gimp, pointers would be appreciated. If there's any other application that can create the maps, preferably free ones, pointers on those would also be appreciated.

What I'm trying to achieve is something along the lines of this:
If I have create a texture/diffuse map like this one:
[image: Diffuse map]
How would I get a roughness map like this one?
[image: Roughness map]

Comment: Hello :). I'm sure you know this, but *any image* can work as a Roughness/Metallic map. In your example you can simply run it through a color ramp an adjust the grey levels :). So what exactly is the problem?